# Inserting result of query in existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi my table zadavatel has following structure

[image]

when I run a query on new data I get some new entries for zadavatel field.This basically gets new zadavatel entries which are not present in former table

```
select distinct zadavatel from [dbo].[DATA_2016_CZ] 
where zadavatel not in (select zadavatel from zadavatel)
```

I need to get this entries into this table, the field advertiser should be for this new entries exact copy of zadavatel field and the value for NOTE should be 2.

if the output of query is like this

[image]

then I want to add to my table

```
zadavatel advertiser note
Al Namura  Al Namura  2
```

and so on for all entries

Can you advise on the query ?

thanks

Comment: what should the output after insert look like? what is the query being used that gets these new values?

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers. Show us what have you try, and what is your desire result.

Comment: [insert into select](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: Edited the details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `insert into..select` to do this.

```
insert into zadavatel (zadavatel, advertiser, note)
select distinct zadavatel , zadavatel, 2
from [dbo].[DATA_2016_CZ] 
where zadavatel not in (select zadavatel from zadavatel)
```

Or

```
insert into zadavatel (zadavatel, advertiser, note)
select distinct zadavatel , zadavatel, 2
from [dbo].[DATA_2016_CZ] d
where not exists (select 1 from zadavatel where zadavatel=d.zadavatel)
```